# jQuery parent()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need some help with parent() in jQuery.

I have a list of images, each followed by a form, where the user can perform some actions, like changing the description of the image etc.

```
<div id='items_list' class='items_list' >               
<div id='item_209' class='item_details' >   
<form action='actions_dispatch2.php' method='post' name='update_image_details' class='form'>
    <input name='originator' type='hidden' value='/list_images3.php' />
    <input name='album_id' type='hidden' value='27' />
    <input name='image_id' type='hidden' value='209' />
    <input name='is_gallery' type='hidden' value='N' />
    <input name='language' type='hidden' value='1' />

<div class='item_img'>
    <img src=' images/square_thumbnails_75x75/209.jpg'/>        
</div> <!-- end div item_img -->

<div class='item_description'>
    <h3> title </h3>
    <h4> some description...</h4>  
</div> <!-- end div item_description -->

<div class='item_buttons' parameters='&album_id=27&image_id=209&is_gallery=N&language=1&originator=/list_images3.php'>
    <a href='/actions_dispatch2.php' action='modify_image' title='Modify' rel='#overlay'>
     <input name='modify_image' type='submit' value='modify' class='button' />
    </a>
</div> <!-- end div item_buttons -->
</form>

</div> <!-- end div item_details (for content to modify)-->     

<div id='item_208' class='item_details' >
<!-- ...and it keeps going with another image... -->
```

I also have a jQuery function that should retrieve some parameters to pass to action_dispatch2.php:

```
$(function() { 

    // if the function argument is given to overlay, 
    // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener 
    $("a[rel]").overlay({ 

    onBeforeLoad: function() { 

    // grab wrapper element inside content 
    var wrap = this.getContent().find(".contentWrap"); 

    // get page to load and action from href attribute in link
    var page_to_load = this.getTrigger().attr("href"); 
    var action = this.getTrigger().attr("action");

    //get parameters from field parameters in parent div (item_buttons)
    var parameters = this.getTrigger().parent().attr("parameters");

    // load the page specified in the trigger 
    wrap.load(page_to_load + "?action=" + action + parameters);

    } 

    }); 
    });
```

Well i'm able to retrieve the href and action attributes, but can't retrieve parameters, which is in the parent()div. the variable parameters gets 'undefined'
The strange thing is that I have another page, very similar (that one shows a list of albums), where i am able to retrieve that parameter ok!

I don't know what the problem could be! can you point me in the right direction?
I have firebug installed but don't know exactly how to use it to track that variable, if possible..

thanks,
patrick

Comment: Would you post a complete minimal test case?

Answer (score 1):

you need `$(this)` instead of `this`. `this` will be the element, therefore in order to call jQuery functions, it needs to be wrapped in a jQuery object by passing into `$()`

```
$(function() { 

        // if the function argument is given to overlay, 
        // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener 
        $("a[rel]").overlay({ 

        onBeforeLoad: function() { 

        // grab wrapper element inside content 

        // store jQuery object in local variable
        var $this = $(this);

        // I would advise using the element tag here
        // instead of just the class as it will be faster 
        // across all browsers
        var wrap = $this.getContent().find(".contentWrap"); 

        // get page to load and action from href attribute in link
        var page_to_load = $this.getTrigger().attr("href"); 
        var action = $this.getTrigger().attr("action");

        //get parameters from field parameters in parent div (item_buttons)
        var parameters = $this.getTrigger().parent().attr("parameters");

        // load the page specified in the trigger 
        wrap.load(page_to_load + "?action=" + action + parameters);

        } 

        }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks Russ, 
actually in this case this (without $) is correct, as it refers to that overlay script (http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay.html#api  "Inside any callback function the this variable is a pointer to the overlay scripting API)

sorry for omitting that.

that parent(), however, is very strange as it works...sometimes!
I've checked the html scripts in both working and not-working cases, and the bits around that Parent div are the same. any other ideas?
thanks
Patrick

Comment: ah, ok *(not quite aligned with jQuery best practice!)*. Have you stepped through with firebug to see what gets returned after each chained command?

Comment: I've tried doing that, but I actually didn't know where to start. What's the way to follow all variables step by step?

Answer (score 1):

I expanded the sample to create a test and... `parameters` held the correct value. What didn't work was passing the parameters to `actions_dispatch2.php`. Try passing the parameters as the second argument to `load(...)`:

```
    wrap.load(page_to_load, "action=" + action + parameters);
```

Edit: Strike that, it works both ways in my test case under Safari 4.0.3 and FF 3.5. It's worth a try, but it's probably not the solution.

We need a complete minimal test case, as what's provided will work.

An alternative is to do away with the "parameters" attribute, which is both non-standard and and unnecessary duplication of the data in the form inputs. Extend jQuery with a method to collect parameters:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn, {parameters:
  function(type) {
    type = type || '';
    var params = this.children('input'+type).map(function (i) {
        if (this.value) {
          return this.name + '=' + this.value;
        } else {
          return this.name;
        }
      }
    );
    return Array.prototype.join.call(params, '&');
  }
});
```

Then, in your onBeforeLoad handler:

```
var parameters = '&' + this.getTrigger().closest('form').parameters(':hidden');
```

You could probably leave out the ':hidden' argument. If you wish, you could alter `parameters` to additionally take multiple types (as e.g. an array of selectors) to get the parameters from multiple input types.

As for Firebug pointers, see:

- [Introduction To Firebug](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/06/introduction-to-firebug/)
- [Build Better Pages With Firebug](http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Build_Better_Pages_With_Firebug)
- [Firebug screencast](http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/screencast/firebug-js/)

Comment: thanks outis, but I would I catch the arguments in actions_dispatch.php? at the moment i catch them as $_GET['parameter_name'], but if I understand correctly from jQuery documentation, they would be passed as post, so I need to remove the initial ? and all &'s?

Comment: Remove the initial "?", but leave the "&"s. Whether you're using GET or POST, you need to separate the fields with "&". Furthermore, `load()` performs a GET by default, not a POST.